# Dropwizard Counter Not Retaining value in Spring Boot App

Tags: spring-boot, dropwizard, graphite, codahale-metrics

I am trying to register the # of spring boot apps I've in my pvt cloud environment. Logic is to use `Counter` metric to `increment` during startUp and `decrement` during shut down. All the different deployments will publish to the same `metricPreFix`(--assumption). 
Following is the graph I get in Graphite:[image: Counter vs Time]

```
#application.properties
spring.metrics.export.delay-millis=100
```

Why do I see the value to come down to `0` even when the app is running? I have tried with 2 different implementations with same result. Can someone please point out the gap in my understanding? PFB the code

```
@Component
public class AppStartupBean implements CommandLineRunner {

private static final String appMetricName = "MyApp.currentCount.GraphOne";
private static final String metricName = "MyApp.currentCount.GraphTwo";

@Autowired
DropwizardMetricServices dwMetricService;

@Autowired
private MetricRegistry registry;

@Override
public void run(String... arg0) throws Exception {
    dwMetricService.increment(appMetricName);

    Counter counter = registry.counter(metricName);
    counter.inc();
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The configuration for `DropwizardMetricServices` was wrong. I was using

```
@Bean
public DropwizardMetricServices dwMetricService(MetricRegistry registry) {
     return new DropwizardMetricServices(registry);
}
```

Instead we should just `@Autowire DropwizardMetricServices` as needed. PFB

> When Dropwizard metrics are in use, the default CounterService and
>   GaugeService are replaced with a DropwizardMetricServices, which is a
>   wrapper around the MetricRegistry (so you can @Autowired one of those
>   services and use it as normal).